# con API tengo un diccionario de monedas extranjeras pero tengo el euro como base y me pide que calcule con libra esterlina GBP

Tags: python, jupyter, python-requests

https://exchangeratesapi.io/
esa es la pagina donde esta el diccionario. necesito con  la libreria requests en python en vez de calcular las monedas con el EUR hacerlo con la GBP, por favor ayuda.

```
import requests r=requests.put('https://exchangeratesapi.io/put', data={'base':'GBP'})
```

r

pero me da error 405 no se como hacer para cambiar base que viene guardada EUR o si se puede hacer de otra forma

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado por tu cuenta? No pretenderás que lo hagan por ti. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Parece que el diccionario ya lo tienes, y que sólo te falta convertirlo de base EUR a base GBP. ¿Correcto?

Comment: import requests
response = requests.get('https://exchangeratesapi.io/events')
response.text
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data={'base': 'GBP'})
response_data=response.json()
response_data

Comment: En vez de escribir esa info en el comentario, mejor haz clic en [edit] y agrégalo a tu pregunta. Saludos